# How to achieve background left and right gradient fades in layout only when window size exceeds 1100px?

Tags: html, css

This has been eating away at my for the past day. What i want to achieve is when the users monitor is viewed at 1100px or less, it only shows a solid background color. When it exceeds that width, a left and right gradient aligned always at the left and right furthest appear, but are not ever shown if the screen size does not exceed 1100px.

Here is an example of what i am trying to do:

[image]

I tried setting up 3 divs, but that doesnt seem to work as show in the JSFiddle below. Any tips or suggestions?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qB48w/181/)

```
<div></div>
```

Comment: If you make the whole thing responsive...  You could set a gradient on the container element with color stops at certain percentages...  Then make your layout match those color stops, so 20%, 60%, 20% - for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a gradient to the `.left` and `.right` divs and hide them when the screen width is below `1100px`.

As an example:

Gradient from dark -> light

```
.left {
    min-width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000000;
    float: left;
    background: #000000;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #000000), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #000000 0%, #ffffff 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#000000', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Grandient from light -> dark

```
.right {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #ffffff;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #000000));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #ffffff 0%, #000000 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#000000', GradientType=1);
    /* IE6-9 */
    background-color: #000;
    float: right;
}
```

(The above gradients are generated from http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Then an `@media` query to hide them below `1100px`

```
@media (max-width: 1100px) {
    .left, .right {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qB48w/183/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: using the @media to hide the side divs works enough for what i was going for. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There are so many methods to achieve what you're trying to do. I'll post the most obvious and leave the intense answers for those who understand your question better.

Your first bet is it to center a div layer using:

```
.myDiv {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-image: url(assets/mybg.jpg);
    background-position: top center;
}
```

Basically, you'll take your background image (with that gradient) and center it, and then center your div layer.

Your background should be made in Photoshop/GIMP/Paint.net/Whateverprogram and the solid color should be 1100px wide. Then the gradient should span the remaining area outside the solid.

My next option for you is to actually do this in jquery. We'll design it so that the div has the gradient until the viewport 1100px or less and it'll transition that background image to a different background image:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function widthCalculator(wrapper, changeWidth){
        var wrapperWidth = $(wrapper).width();
        if (wrapperWidth <= changeWidth) {
            $(wrapper).css("background-image", "url(Assets/mybackground2.jpg)");
        } else {
            $(wrapper).css("background-image", "url(Assets/mybackground1.jpg)");
        }
    }
    widthCalculator('#wrapper', 1100);
    $(window).resize(function(){ widthCalculator('#wrapper', 1100); });
});
</script>
<style>

body {
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5000px;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The jquery method isn't the best solution, because upon resize, it loads a new background. If you're desperate, and looking for a quick fix, this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a try it the above does not work. love the suggestion

Comment: If you're interested in changing the code a little bit, in JQuery, the .css() property works like this:

`$(-element-.css("-property to add-", "-value of property-")`

So for my recommendation, you can simply just change:

`$(wrapper).css("background-image", "url(Assets/mybackground2.jpg)");`

to:

`$(wrapper).css("background-color", "red");`

And you'll produce the results you're looking for.